# Flutter: new version package cannot get past apple review

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store, version, app-store-connect

Im implementing the New Version package, which takes the version number of the current build from the app store, and compares it to the local build. If they are different, it shows a dialogue that wont leave until the app is updated.

However, this is the problem. When i submit my app to review, new Version  takes the current app store version, 1.4. The submitted build is 1.5. Therefore, it launches the dialogue and will not go away, causing the review process to fail. Anyone have a workaround?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What work best for me is wrapping logic in "get current build version" to backend or just simply Firebase. There will be many cases you don't want yourself binding to directly comparing version in your mobile app.

So better control it in your way.

Comment: If you're not using firebase in your app (which is rare), there are many alternatives.